# Implement Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern In A Portable Class

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, portable-class-library

I have a few c# class libraries which I share between applications. I want to create a Windows 8 Style App, but it only supports windows 8 class libraries or [portable class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx).
Deciding to go with the later I've ported everything without too much difficulty with the exception of Async operations.

Currently my class libraries are implementing the [Event-based Asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wy069k1.aspx).

From this example a portable library doesn't seem to support `System.Componenent.AsyncOperation/AsyncOperationManager` and `System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary`.

My two questions are:

1) What is a good collection to use instead of `HybridDictionary`?

2) How can I get around the lack of `AsyncOperation/AsyncOperationManager`? Do I need to implement a completely different pattern?

UPDATE: In VS 2012 my Portable class library is targeting
".net framework 4 and higher", "Silverlight 4 and higher", "windows phone 7 and higher", ".net for metro style apps".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) How many elements are you using in HybridDictionary? If under 10), just use List<T>. Otherwise, use Dictionary<Key, TValue>.

2) I've got a portable version of AsyncOperation/AsyncOperationManager and BackgroundWorker over on http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/. There's no binaries yet, but just browse the Portable.ComponentModel.Async project for the source code.

Comment: Thanks. Nice work on the portable version. Shame you had to put in the effort where MS didn't.

Comment: Thanks. I work for Microsoft, so in effect Microsoft did do this. :)  The reason HybridDictionary and AsyncOperation aren't available is because they are considered legacy, and something we don't want to carry forward to newer platforms.